# Multiple back-reference properties with name 'defaultReference'

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have multiple back-reference classes in a class. Since I use `@JsonBackReference` for them, I get an error. I assigned `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotation for those classes, but I still get the same error.

```
public class X implements Serializable {
  ....
  //bi-directional many-to-one association to Booking
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "xxA", nullable = false)
  @JsonBackReference
  private A a;

  //bi-directional many-to-one association to Client
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "xxB", nullable = false)
  @JsonBackReference
  private B b;
  ...getters setters
}

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@id")
public class B implements Serializable {
  ........ 
  //bi-directional many-to-one association to BookedClient
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "b", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JsonManagedReference
  private List < X > xxB;
  ........ getters setters
}


@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@id")
public class A implements Serializable {
  ........
  //bi-directional many-to-one association to BookedClient
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JsonManagedReference
  private List < X > xxA;
  ........ getters setters
}
```

error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Multiple back-reference properties with name 'defaultReference'

How can I resolve this error? Can I not use multiple back-reference in a class?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Jackson's javadoc](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonManagedReference.html), both `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` accept a name value that binds them together:

```
  @JsonBackReference("a")
  private A a;

  @JsonManagedReference("a")
  private List < X > xxA;
```

Comment: I added a name value for each relation. I still get the same error.

Comment: Yes, I also tried as `@JsonManagedReference(value="a")`, `@JsonBackReference(value="a")` and still the same error

Comment: i get this error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not handle managed/back reference 'a': back reference type (java.util.List) not compatible with managed type (A)`

Comment: @Eniss You must name **all** of Your back/managed references with unique names, since they might conflict with other references in the project. Just give each pair of `@JasonBackReference` ~ `@JasoManagedReference` a unique, sensible name. Did You solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue, but in the last I resolved it.

```
//This is parent class
@Entity
@Table(name = "checklist")
@JsonIgnoreProperties("inspection")
public class Checklist implements java.io.Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Product product;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "checklists", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Inspection> inspection = new HashSet<Inspection>();
//Constructor
//Getter and Setter
}

//This is child class
@Entity
@Table(name = "inspections")
public class Inspection {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "chk_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Checklist checklists;
//Constructor
//Getter and Setter
}
```

By mentioning   `@JsonIgnoreProperties("inspection")` and `@JsonManagedReference` in Parent class

Resolved the issue raised by using two `@JSONBackRefrence` in same parent class.

Answer (score 0):

So this did actually take me a while...

You can annotate your referencse accordingly using `@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)` and then leave it off the master reference

```
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
    private Set<PackInstructionGroup> groups = new TreeSet<>();
```